# Rewrite Engine .htaccess MIME type error

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a script that make search and I want the results also be accessible with query

```
mysite.com/searchfor/"myword"
```

I added next lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/?searchfor/(.*)$ search.php?search=$1 [L]
```

It works (the page is loading), but every linked resource (css/js) failed to load with next error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

These lines refer to mysite.com/searchfor/theme.css, but it is wrong, as the right link to the css is mysite.com/theme.css.

I suspect RewriteEngine giving wrong path to load styles and scripts what failed it.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?searchfor/(.+)$ search.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What happens if you try to open just the css file using its URL in a browser?

Comment: It openes my search page with css name as search. For example, opening theme.css will search for "theme.css"

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". For each script or css

Comment: ok that is a progress since css is not going to `search.php` anymore. Now see what exact 404 message you get for this css file and why that path isn't valid. Better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: I thought that relatives paths are better, as you can move your foulder to anywhere and it will work.

Comment: Relative paths create so many problems while dealing with pretty URL schemes (imagine presence of multiple slashes in a pretty URL path). Even if you have to move css/js paths in future you can maintain same css/js URL path using either symlinks OR aliases OR redirect rules.

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect RewriteEngine giving wrong path to load styles and scripts what failed it.

Not the RewriteEngine is giving the wrong paths – your HTML is.

If you refer your scripts and stylesheets relative to the path the client has requested, then it of course make a difference whether the client requested `example.com/foo` or `example.com/searchfor/bar` – since relative paths are resolved in relation to the location of the current document.

> How to solve this?

The easiest way is to reference external resources relative to the domain, beginning with a slash – instead of `script.js` you use `/script.js`, that tells the client that he has to complete this path with the domain only.

Comment: Is it possible to create folder called searchfor and reference all request above via .htaccess???