# .htaccess setup for pretty url with submenu

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I would like to create a simple page with pretty url and a two-level menu. I use a directory in localhost, but of course, on the server i don't (That's why i commented the RewriteBase).
I've have the following .htaccess setup:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&type=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And there is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>htaccess test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="img/image.png" alt="image" />
    <br />
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="aboutus">About us</a>
    <a href="gallery">Gallery</a>
    <a href="help">Help</a>
    <?php
        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'unknown';
        echo "<h1>$page</h1>";
        if ($page == 'gallery') {
            ?>
                <a href="gallery/funny">Funny</a>
                <a href="gallery/beauty">Beauty</a>
                <a href="gallery/interesting">Interesting</a>
            <?php
        }
        $submenu = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : 'unknown';
        if ($submenu != 'unknown') {
            echo "<h2>$submenu</h2>";
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to use only 2 url parameter, the `page` and the `type`. The `page` should be the first directory in the pretty url, the `type` the second.

The main menu works great. When I  click on a sub-menu in the Gallery the page loads but the images don't load as the  parameter is added to their paths. When I click on another submenu, the `page` parameter is duplicated in the url.

I know it must be a pretty easy step but i'm completely stuck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331844/rewrite-engine-htaccess-mime-type-error/21332806#21332806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the links will be interpreted as relative to the current url path. So you either have to provide an appropriate `<base>` tag or create the links as absolute (e.g. `/gallery/funny`).

Comment: I tried with the appropriate RewriteBase, but not better. The images already handled by the RewriteRule, but i previously put the conditions (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`)...

Comment: No `RewriteBase` won't make a difference, best is to have links as the answer says i.e. `/gallery/funny`